# React webpack bundle component splitting

Tags: reactjs, webpack, code-splitting

So I have a component that does "require" some local images. That component only displays on dashboard (main page) and basically the images are like the dashboard background. (like a carousel).

What I want: When I build the app with webpack I don't want to load js bundle that contains images if I don't open the Dahsboard page directly. For example if I open /users/etc.

I should mention that I use react router and at `/` the Dashboard component loads and the Dashboard component loads multiple `DashboardOffer` components that each one `requires` a local image

I tried this:

```
const DashboardOffer = require('./DashboardOffer').default;
```

And then use the component like this in my code instead of the default `import`. But it doesn't work, it still loads that js bundle with 7mb of images everywhere I load my app.

How could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should use [`file-loader`](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) (with Webpack <5) or [`Asset Module`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images) (with Webpack >= 5). Instead of putting these images inside your bundle as Data URI, these loaders will copy your images separately into the final `dist` folder. For anytime you are doing `import MyImage from './my-image.png'`, the `MyImage` variable will hold path to the image that you can set as `src` - `<img src=${MyImage} />`.

With this you won't need code splitting. You should consider code splitting for views that depends on large external libraries like that once that deal with Maps, Editors, etc. which are used only on certain views. Further, using `require` doesn't cause code splitting. You need to use dynamic `import` for this.